# Core Location question

Tags: objective-c, iphone, core-location

[This tutorial on mobileorchard.com](http://www.mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) uses 2 classes (or 2 sets of .h and .m) to implement core location. Can I just use everything there in my existing class? How would I do that?

Can I use my existing app delegate as a location delegate as well?

Also, is the

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self; // send loc updates to myself
    }
    return self;
}
```

method the same as the usual `initWithNib`?

I'm trying to quickly implement something based on location information. As much help describing the above linked tutorial would be helpful.

Thanks. No - really, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure. You can make your delegate a location manager delegate too. You'll just need to implement CLLocationManagerDelegate there with the method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

to get location updates.

Comment: ... and I follow that with implementing the corresponding class methods in my class?